# Finding the difference between rows given the date and variable

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

Good day!

I need to find the difference of a specific series between two dates if only the month is greater than one (anything from February to December).

Suppose I have a table

```
  Date / variable / value
  Jan.08 / a / 2
  Jan.08 /b / 3
  Feb.08 / a / 5
  Feb.08 / b / 8
```

I need the following result

```
  Date / variable / value / diff
  Jan.08 / a / 2 / 2
  Jan.08 /b / 3 / 3
  Feb.08 / a / 5 / 3
  Feb.08 / b / 8 / 5
```

I used this function

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df_tests)) {
  if (format(df_tests$Date, "%m")!="01") {
    df_tests[,4] <- ave(df_tests$value, df_tests$variable, FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
  } else {
    df_tests[,4] <- df_tests$value
  }
}
```

But it does only the second part of statement
`df_tests[,4] <- df_tests$value`
and I get this result

```
  Date / variable / value / diff
  Jan.08 / a / 2 / 2
  Jan.08 /b / 3 / 3
  Feb.08 / a / 5 / 5
  Feb.08 / b / 8 / 8
```

Any thougths on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Can you please help me to understand your desired results. I assume that diff for 'Feb.08 / a' is value b - value a, i.e. 8 - 5 = 3. But how do you calculate diff for 'Feb.08 / b'? Sorry I have overlooked something very obvious. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df_tests)) {
  if (format(as.Date(paste("01.", df.tests$Date[i], sep = ""), format = "%d.%b.%y"), "%m")=="01") {
    df_tests[i,4] <- ave(df_tests$value, df_tests$variable, FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))[i]
  } else {
    df_tests[i,4] <- df_tests$value[i]
  }
}
```